# Couchbase timeout on bucket operation when in K8S pod

Tags: java, couchbase, kubernetes

I was able to narrow down my problem to the following case:

I'm creating Kubernetes pod with two containers:

- couchbase - initialized version with one bucket from offical Couchbase 3.1 image
- my java app that tries to connect to Couchbase and use this bucket

My app's code is as follows (full content of main function):

```
    CouchbaseEnvironment ce = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .connectTimeout(10000)
            .build();
    CouchbaseCluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(ce, "127.0.0.1");
    Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("my_user", "some_pass");
    JsonObject jo = JsonObject.empty();
    jo.put("SomeName", "someValue");
    bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create("my_id", jo));
```

It fails on last command with timeout:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:267)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:262)
    at CConfig.main(CConfig.java:19)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    ... 10 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:93)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:267)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:262)
    at CConfig.main(CConfig.java:19)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    ... 10 more
```

I don't know how to fix this or get to the root cause as timeout is very unlikely as the Couchbase is having only one, empty bucket.

PS when configured logs for Couchbase client I was able to see *keep-alive* entries working just fine.

I'm using official Couchbase java client in version 2.1.0. Also tried 2.1.6 and 2.2.5 but no luck.

Comment: The error message indicates that the application is not able to connect to Couchbase server. Why are you using 127.0.0.1 to connect?

Kubernetes pod IP addresses are ephemeral and should never be accessed directly. http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/couchbase-on-kubernetes explains how to expose a Couchbase pod and make it accessible outside Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: The thing is that I'm able to connect to Couchbase server. As I mentioned, I'm getting keep-alive successful etc. Also I think it would fail few lines before if it wasn't able to connect to Couchbase...

Comment: I'm using 127.0.0.1 because those two containers land in the same pod. I did this to narrow my problem, as even as separate pods I had problem :/

Comment: Are you explicitly packaging two containers as one pod? This is not considered a recommended practice AIU. You should really be front-ending your pod with a Service and then use that IP address for connecting to Couchbase.

Comment: Trust me, I'm totally aware of this. I had troubles with it so I reduced the case to the bare problem that I was hitting and still I wasn't able to tell why only "part" of connection works :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was created by me - the bucket I have created didn't had password set and I tried to connect to it with password...

I wanted to delete whole answer but I thought that it might be helpful in case someone else have similar problem

Comment: Glad you figured it out. The error message seems incorrect though. Do you mind filing a bug at https://issues.couchbase.com/?